# WPF GridViewColumn's DisplayMemberBinding using a Dictionary Key's Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I haven't found anything similiar to this on Stack or Google, so maybe it isnt' possible, but hopefully someone smart will have an idea.  I'm a bit of a noobie to WPF/XAML.

I have a custom class that resembles something similiar to this.

```
public class LogEntry
{
   public Diciontary<string, string> Stuff;
   public string MyOtherProperty;   
}
```

My GridView will have 2 columns.  One for MyOtherProperty and one for Stuff["Stuff1"].  Assuming I *cannot* change the Diciontary to something a lot easier to bind to.

I am binding my ListView to a `List<LogEntry>`. How would I accomplish it in this scenario.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MyOtherProperty}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="**{Binding Stuff[Stuff1]}**"></GridViewColumn>
         </GridView.Columns>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525333/wpf-binding-dictionarystring-liststring-to-listview-listbox-how

Comment: No, I don't think it's a duplicate of that.  The ItemsSource is the List not the dictionary in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF supports binding to properties and not fields. Change LogEntry class to below and it should work.

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Stuff { get; set; }
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. It's always those simple issues that make you scratch your head.